# Which venue has been open 24/7 for the longest time without any breaks?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids

There are tens of thousands of various establishments worldwide which are normally open 24/7 - bars, restaurants, pubs, hotels, gas stations, etc. Many of them do have small breaks throughout the year - e.g. for Christmas or for maintenance works. I would like to visit the venue which holds the record for being open without any breaks for the longest period of time. The restrictions are:

1. The place must have clearly defined boundaries and must have the capability to close - so beaches or forests are excluded.
2. The venue must be focused on commercial services of some kind - so free public parks or squares are excluded. However things like public libraries are okay, since those usually charge money for membership or loaning books.
3. The location must not be a waiting area - e.g. an airport terminal or a train station won't fit, however an airport shop would.
4. The place must be accessible by anyone - so things like hospitals or private offices are excluded.
5. There must be no breaks of any kind - one could get there at 3AM on Christmas day and expect it to be open.

Comment: Requirement #2 unfortunately eliminates churches and temples.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan are there 24/7 churches?

Comment: @JonathanReez Does it have to be staffed?  Otherwise plenty of self-service mountain huts are always open.  If yes, that would eliminate most always-open churches and temples.

Comment: @gerrit I presume you're speaking of guys where you leave some money in a box to pay for your stay? If so, are they never closed for reconstruction?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, or it otherwise has instructions on how to pay (transfer money etc.), or is paid for by sponsorship or other donations.  I suppose they may be sometimes closed for reconstruction, but if it's a larger unit that has multiple buildings then they might never close all buildings at once. In the end you may have to define "venue".  I don't suppose a cave which people may have used for tens of thousands of years and still do counts as a venue? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think casinos in Las Vegas are good candidates. They are open even on Christmas. I didn't find any official records but I had read once that the last time they all were closed was in 1963 (when J.F. Kennedy was killed). So, the casinos which existed then and still exist (f.e. Golden Gate) are the best candidates.

Comment: You need to check March 11, 1970, most hotels (and casinos) closed due to the strike and while the Riviera stayed open, it was closed demolished recently.

Comment: @chx Yes. And renovations/reconstructions too.

Comment: The casinos are closing again, due to coronavirus: https://www.rgj.com/story/news/2020/03/15/las-vegas-strip-resorts-now-closing-first-up-wynn-and-encore/5056092002/

Answer (score -3):

Official record? I have no idea.

A very good candidate? [This newsstand](https://www.google.it/maps/place/43%C2%B052'00.7%22N+10%C2%B014'37.0%22E/@43.8668611,10.2430639,165m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d43.866855!4d10.243602?hl=it) in Viareggio, Tuscany. I don't remember to have ever seen it closed.

Comment: (and yes, I'm serious. I can't remember a single, damn day when they weren't open. Obviously they must have closed for at least a bit of maintenance, still I can't remember it having ever happened)

Comment: Do you have any form of source at all for this claim? Is it some famous stand, are they even open 24 hours a day? Does the stand have a name or website?

Comment: @skifans nothing famous, it is just a newsstand. Why should it be famous?

Comment: Is it *really* open 24 hours a day, seven days a week, 365 days a year? Like, even at 3 AM on Christmas morning?